# Login / Registration bar

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping a header always in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559449/keeping-a-header-always-in-view)

I want to know how to be able to create a bar that's stuck on to the top of the page.

[image]

Sort of like this. Are there any tutorials as to how I can make them on my website.